# Json.NET (De)serialize MailAddress

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

After looking at many Google searches and StackOverflow posts I've com to the conclusion I may nee to create my own converter. However, this is very, very new to me and I'm not sure which, if any, of the examples I see in these posts am I to use.

I have this class (actual class is more complex than this)

```
public class Person {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string PersonId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstName")]
    public string PersonFirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
    public MailAddress PersonEmail { get; set; }
}
```

I need to serialize and deserialize the following json

```
{
    "id" : "abc123"
    , "firstName" : "John"
    , "email" : "john@doe.com"
}
```

How do I deserialize the MailAddress to a `string` containing `MailAddress.Address` and vice-versa.

The error I get is:

> Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress

Comment: what is the issue you are having? Json.NET should do that with eyes closed.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, as you can see here https://dotnetfiddle.net/XbUVci it does not work.

Comment: @kiziu thanks. ur too fast =)

Comment: Do us all a favor and *copy* the exception you're getting into the question.

Comment: Why did this get 1) a down vote within explanation, and 2) a vote to close for `off-topic because...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Json.NET doesn't play well with some .Net types like `System.Net.IPAddress` or `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`. Unless you're willing to modify your JSON, then you'll have to write a custom converter in order to use them (code taken from [here](http://code-smart.org.uk/techniques/serialising-constructor-less-net-types-e-g-mailaddress-using-newtonsoft-json-jsonconvert-in-the-json-net-library/)):

```
public class MailAddressConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var mailAddress = value as MailAddress;
        writer.WriteValue(mailAddress == null? string.Empty : mailAddress.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var text = reader.Value as string;
        MailAddress mailAddress;

        return IsValidMailAddress(text, out mailAddress) ? mailAddress : null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MailAddress);
    }

    private static bool IsValidMailAddress(string text, out MailAddress value)
    {
        try
        {
            value = new MailAddress(text);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can either modify your class as the author of that post suggests:

```
public class Person 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string PersonId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstName")]
    public string PersonFirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MailAddressConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
    public MailAddress PersonEmail { get; set; }
}
```

..*or*, you can use my preferred approach, which is to use Json.NET's [`JsonSerializerSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm):

```
public sealed class SerializerSettings : JsonSerializerSettings
{
    public SerializerSettings() : base()
    {
        this.Converters.Add(new MailAddressConverter());
    }
}
```

Then in your `Main()`:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new SerializerSettings();
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I suck at Googling, even after all these years. You know I was searching `C# Newtonsoft.Json MailAddress` and this article didn't show up, but change it to `C# Json.Net MailAddress` and it's 4th in line. This looks good. I'll try it.

Comment: I think the standard approach of `JsonConverter` is not to check if value provided is valid for given type, just let the constructor/parser sort it out and throw exceptions if it fails to do so. Take a look here - https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs, it does not catch anything, simply runs parsing.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs Having dealt with this sort of problem in the past (for `IPAddress` and `IPEndpoint` objects), I immediately recognized the error and only needed to search for `C# newtonsoft MailAddress converter`.

Answer (score 2):

Your json structure needs to be like this because `MailAddress` is an object:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "George",
    "email": {
        "DisplayName": "",
        "User": "test",
        "Host": "test.com",
        "Address": "test@test.com"
    }
}
```

You can do a quick test like this to see the JSON that is produced:

```
var person = new Person
{
    PersonEmail = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@test.com"),
    PersonFirstName = "George",
    PersonId = "1"
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot change the Json as it's a 3rd party data. Using Salesforce API to be exact.